# how can I remove layer in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I want to remove the decoder portion of the Autoencoder.

and I want to put FC in the removed part.

In addition, the encoder parts will not train with pre-learned weights.

```
    self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        nn.Conv2d(16, 8, 3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        nn.Conv2d(8, 8, 3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=4, stride=1),

    )
    self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(8, 8, 3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(8, 8, kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        nn.Conv2d(8, 8, 3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(8, 8, kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        nn.Conv2d(8, 16, 3),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 16, kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        nn.Conv2d(16, 1, 3, padding=1)
    )
    def forward(self, x):
       if self.training :
           x = self.encoder(x)
           x = self.decoder(x)
           return x
       else:
           x = classifier(x)
           return x
```

is this possible?
help me...

Comment: I just made a model. I'll refer to the Pytorch Tutorial. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One easy and clean solution would be to define a stand-alone network as your decoder, then replace the decoder attribute of your model with this new network after pre-training is over. Easy example below:

```
class sillyExample(torch.nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
       super(sillyExample, self).__init__()
       self.encoder = torch.nn.Linear(5, 5)
       self.decoder = torch.nn.Linear(5, 10)

   def forward(self, x):
       return self.decoder(self.encoder(x))

test = sillyExample()
test(torch.rand(30, 5)).shape
Out: torch.Size([30, 10]) 
test.decoder = torch.nn.Linear(5, 20)  # replace the decoder
test(torch.rand(30, 5)).shape
Out: torch.Size([30, 20])
```

Just make sure to re-initialize your optimizers with the updated model (or anything else that might be referencing the model's parameters).